# how do I set a proxy server in my headless chrome request using Node JS Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, headless-browser, puppeteer

/*I am  running a headless search request on chrome and i need to access a proxy server*/

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var url="https://www.google.com/search?q=";
var keyword="hotels";
var urls;
var desktopUserAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36";
const response=[];
var i=0;
var userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36";

(async () => {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  urls=url+keyword;

page.setUserAgent(userAgent);
  response[i]=await page.goto(urls);
  console.log(await browser.version());
})();
```

//i need to able to access a proxy server in order to google search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass in a proxy like this in an argument,

```
const options = {
        headless: false,
        args: [
            `--proxy-server=${proxyIP:proxyPORT}`,
            `--ignore-certificate-errors`
        ]
};
const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);
```

If you want proxy authentication, you can use the following in your page object,

```
await page.authenticate(user, pass);
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a module that does this. It's called [**puppeteer-page-proxy**](https://github.com/Cuadrix/puppeteer-page-proxy).
It supports setting a proxy for an entire page, or if you like, it can set a different proxy for each request.

First install it:

```
npm i puppeteer-page-proxy
```

Then require it:

```js
const useProxy = require('puppeteer-page-proxy');
```

**Using it is easy;**
Set proxy for an entire page:

```js
await useProxy(page, 'http://127.0.0.1:8000');
```

If you want a different proxy for each request,then you can simply do this:

```js
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', req => {
    useProxy(req, 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9000');
});
```

Then if you want to be sure that your page's IP has changed, you can look it up;

```js
const data = await useProxy.lookup(page);
console.log(data.ip);
```

It supports **http**, **https**, **socks4** and **socks5** proxies, and it also supports authentication if that is needed:

```js
const proxy = 'http://login:pass@127.0.0.1:8000'
```

Repository:
https://github.com/Cuadrix/puppeteer-page-proxy