# how to connect puppeteer with an open chrome browser using authenticated proxies

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, automation, puppeteer

so am connection puppeteer to an already opened chrome browser  Using This Peace of code

```
    const browserURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:9222';
    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserURL , defaultViewport : null  });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
```

but most of the times i want to connect to the browser using an authenticated proxies , maybe launching the chrome with specific flags ?

i tried proxy-login-Automator and it would launch chrome with authenticated proxy that i would connect to it but this so complicated if i want to keep changing proxies + if am using many  instances of the same code

am launching Chrome with this.

```
chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
```

Comment: Please be more specific in your questions, don't try to ask multiple things at once (it may also even help you to understand the solution). So what's the problem?

Comment: hi, am connecting puppeteer to an Chrome instance , what i want to do is when i launch the Chrome instance i want to launch it with an authenticated proxy so i dont get caught , thank you

Comment: See reply here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46957336/how-do-i-set-a-proxy-server-in-my-headless-chrome-request-using-node-js-puppetee?rq=4